# ASP.NET MVC Project does not show correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Relatively new to `VC 2019` and working on an `ASP.NET MVC` tutorial. After the implementation of the View, Model, and Controller classes, when I run the service, my upper menu is gone :/

I am not sure if this is a coding or library error is. I also am not sure how to debug this.

Please advice,
AUU

[Menu is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6mNx.png)

Comment: do you reference multiple bootstrap (3 and 4) reference?

Comment: Hi Mehmet, I have 4.5.3 bootstrap installed on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that "`navbar`" class exists in div tag of _Layout page is deleted or changed to `display:none`. The attached image shows that the Navbar for menu buttons comes from this master page named `_Layout.cshtml`

The navbar that looks:

[image: the navbar that looks]

Nav bar from _Layout.cshtml page:

[image]

Comment: I compared the content with a blank project and the html contents are very similar apart from one page I added. I can only guess the dependencies are different from eachother. How can I get a full list ?